# Populating an array value in elasticsearch query

Tags: elasticsearch

My partial elasticsearch query is as:

> "match_phrase":{
>               "taskId.keyword":{
>                 "query": ""
>               }

I set taskId dynamically in my js program. But this struture allows me to set it to a single id, and hence a call fetches only a single record.

I can have multiple task idsin my program. So I want to fetch records for an array of task ids.

How do I structure my query for it?

Can I do like this:

> "match_phrase":{"taskId.keyword":{"query": []
>               }

And then set array dynamically:

> ....match_phrase['taskId.keyword'] = dynamically calculated task id array

Answer (score 0):

You can use [terms query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html) for matching multiple taskIds.
Use the query as below:

```
{
  "query":{
    "terms":{
      "taskId.keyword":["taskId1", "taskId2", "taskId3"]
    }
  }
}
```

You can replace `["taskId1", "taskId2", "taskId3"]` with a dynamically created taskId array in your application code.